# Mobile UX prototyping tools in the classroom

Tags: gui-design, android, ios, wireframe, prototype

*(I know this sounds like a repeat question, but I am asking this specifically for a classroom context and I have some specific needs (other than "free") that I feel sets this question apart.  Please do not close it without reading.)*

I am teaching a very introductory course in interface design and user experience.

My students have used PowerPoint to create low-fidelity website wireframes and clickable prototypes.  They are comfortable with this process, as they use PowerPoint quite a bit.

I am seeking a collection of **stencils/images that can be easily placed in PowerPoint** to allow them to create wireframes for *BOTH iOS and Android applications*.  The wireframes will be the basis for clickable prototypes.

I understand that Google has produced images that can be used in high-fidelity mockups.  However, we are working mostly with low-fi images (think: Balsamiq's sketchiness.)  Even in low-fi mockups I think it is extremely important to start to note the differences between the platforms' layouts and UI elements.

We don't have access to $ for software (which is why we have been using PowerPoint.)  If there are other tools that have free access for educational use, I need them to cover *BOTH iOS and Android* (myBalsamiq, while great in many respects, does not have Android UI elements.)  The software must also allow students to **export their prototypes** (so they can be submitted for grading.)  I haven't found a satisfactory tool that does this.

Does anyone have any ideas short of me just drawing the elements in PowerPoint myself?

Comment: "Even in low-fi mockups I think it is extremely important to start to note the differences between the platforms' layouts and UI elements" = then that's not Low-fi.

Answer (score 5):

For starters, Balasamiq does have a very thriving community who do voluntarily design stencils/mockups of various interface elements and there are android elements available at The Mockups to go site ([Android Controls](https://mockupstogo.mybalsamiq.com/projects/android/grid))

The IOS elements for Balsamiq can also be found [here](https://mockupstogo.mybalsamiq.com/projects/ios/grid)

Do check out [Axure's good student program](https://www.axure.com/free-software-for-students). I am not sure if your students qualify for the program but its worth having a look. To provide a quick summary :

> **Requirements**
>
> - Must be a full-time undergraduate student or full or part-time    graduate student
> - Must be studying HCI, user experience, information    architecture, interaction design, or other related field with a GPA
>     of 3.0 or higher in the last semester (or equivalent in your grading
>     system)
> - Must have grades clearly stated on transcript Graduate    students without a transcript will be considered with proof of    registration
>     in a related course
> - Must provide school email address

I also recommend looking at the [Pencil Project](http://www.evolus.vn/en-US/Products/Pencil.aspx). I do know they have some predefined stencils for [iOS](http://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/downloads/detail?name=iOSWireframe.zip) and [Android](http://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/downloads/list?can=1&q=android)

[Tiggzi](http://tiggzi.com/home) also looks interesting. I believe they do offer free standard plans or educational discounts but you would have to touchbase with them for that.

Also check out [Justinmind free edition](http://www.justinmind.com/prototyper/free-edition) (They have out of box android/Ios widgets which are available in the free edition but the prototyping functionality is not available)

There are also [powerpoint stencils available for both iOS and Android](http://keynotopia.com/) but you have to pay for them, so I am not sure how agreeable an option that is.

Answer (score 0):

fluidui is also very useful tool as mobile prototyping.
http://www.fluidui.com/

Comment: This isn't an answer for SE, as you probably already know judging from the flag, it's just a link. I doesn't provide an answer to the question, and it's far from free.